# Reflection error unit testing Java with Cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber

I am running one simple cucumber test.

While running I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

My Runner class is -

```
package com.my.automation;

import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"html:target/cucumber-html","json:target/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-junit/cukey-junit_results.xml"},
                  features = {"src/test/resources/com/my/automation/cuketest/CukeTest.feature"} )

public class RunTest {

}
```

Comment: can you give the whole exception and the feature and step files?

Comment: Hi, Please find whole exception